# onfinish fires early when using SoundManager2

Tags: javascript, audio, soundmanager2

I'm trying to fire a function when my sound in SoundManager2 is finished playing, using onfinished. My code is as follows:

```
function createSound(id, path) {
    mySound = soundManager.createSound({
            id: id,
            url: path,
            volume: 100,
            onfinish: playNextSound(id),
            (...)
            },
    });
    return mySound;
}

function playNextSound(id) {
    (...)
    alert("Done!");
}
```

However, what happens is that the function fires (and the alert is shown) whenever I click play, which is obviously not what is supposed to happen. I've tried putting the onfinish inside the play() function as well, to no avail.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're executing the `playNextSound` function and assigning its returned value to `onfinish`.

You should be doing it like this:

```
onfinish: playNextSound,
```

Comment: How will I then pass arguments to playNextSound? Do I have to inline the function? (It's quite long...)

Comment: Just put the `playNextSound` function inside the `createSound` function and make sure to remove the `id` parameter from the function declaration: `function playNextSound() {`. Any references to `id` inside the function will then be referring to the `id` passed into `createSound`.